# What's best SQL datatype for storing JSON string?

Tags: sql, sql-server, json

What's the best SQL datatype for storing JSON string?

```
static List<ProductModel> CreateProductList()
{
    string json = @"[
        {
            ProductId: 1, 
            ProductCode: 'A', 
            Product: 'A'
        },
        {
            ProductId: 2, 
            ProductCode: 'B', 
            Product: 'B'
        }
    ]";

    IList<JToken> tokenList = JToken.Parse(json).ToList();
    List<ProductModel> productList = new List<ProductModel>();

    foreach (JToken token in tokenList)
    {
        productList.Add(JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<ProductModel>(token.ToString()));
    }

    return productList;
}
```

Which SQL datatype should we use for storing such a string containing JSON?

- `NVARCHAR(255)`?
- `TEXT`?
- `VARBINARY(MAX)`?

Comment: Just some random noise (the comment, not the data): You might want to compress it too. In that case you need something binary. On the other hand: why not just design proper tables for the data?

Comment: @The Nail: Sometimes storing something as JSON (or as a "document") is proper for the need.  Like for a workflow engine or document management etc...I'm doing this on a current project, actually going from relational to document approach for the command side of my CQRS implementation.  It's very fast if you use a serializer such as ServiceStack or JSON.Net.

Answer (score 225):

Certainly **NOT**:

- `TEXT, NTEXT`: those types are **deprecated** as of SQL Server 2005 and should not be used for new development. Use `VARCHAR(MAX)` or `NVARCHAR(MAX)` instead
- `IMAGE`, `VARBINARY(MAX)` : `IMAGE` is deprecated just like `TEXT/NTEXT`, and there's really no point in storing a text string into a binary column....

So that basically leaves `VARCHAR(x)` or `NVARCHAR(x)`: `VARCHAR` stores non-Unicode strings (1 byte per character) and `NVARCHAR` stores everything in a 2-byte-per-character Unicode mode. So do you need Unicode? Do you have Arabic, Hebrew, Chinese or other non-Western-European characters in your strings, potentially? Then go with `NVARCHAR`

The `(N)VARCHAR` columns come in two flavors: either you define a maximum length that results in 8000 bytes or less (`VARCHAR` up to 8000 characters, `NVARCHAR` up to 4000), or if that's not enough, use the `(N)VARCHAR(MAX)` versions, which store up to 2 GByte of data.

**Update:** SQL Server **2016** will have native JSON support - a new `JSON` datatype (which is based on `nvarchar`) will be introduced, as well as a `FOR JSON` command to convert output from a query into JSON format

**Update #2:** in the final product, Microsoft did not include a separate `JSON` datatype - instead, there are a number of JSON-functions (to package up database rows into JSON, or to parse JSON into relational data) which operate on columns of type `NVARCHAR(n)`

Comment: NVARCHAR should be the preferred choice as sql server 2016 will use it for its native JSON support http://blogs.msdn.com/b/jocapc/archive/2015/05/16/json-support-in-sql-server-2016.aspx

Comment: @marc_s Is your "update" statement correct?  I can't find any official JSON Data types... ?

Comment: @Nix: I think in the end, SQL Server supports *JSON functions* that operate on `NVARCHAR(n)` data types

Comment: You might want to update your answer to not state there is a Json data type

Comment: varbinary(max) could be used when using compression

Comment: As mentioned by Marat, I reduced my storage footprint by 80% using VARBINARY(max) and compression. It will take more time to compress/decompress but my storage concerns outweighed performance in this case. If you have large objects then it may be worth looking into.

Comment: At some point you will need an "Update 3" https://techcommunity.microsoft.com/t5/azure-sql-blog/native-json-type-amp-json-aggregates-are-now-in-private-preview/ba-p/3830753

Answer (score 34):

I shall go for **`nvarchar(max)`**. That should fit the requirement.

**Update:**
With SQL Server 2016 and Azure SQL, there are a lot of additional native JSON capabilities. This might positively impact your design or approach. You may read this for more: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/json/json-data-sql-server

Comment: Do you **really** need the 2-byte-per-character Unicode storage?? Depending on your data - it might just be wasting twice as much bytes as needed... (but if you **DO** need Unicode - then that's the only way to go, I agree!)

Comment: nvarchar - because the data is not defined. If we feel that the system will not need unicode, we can save moving to varchar(max)

Comment: Also, using `nvarchar` avoids the collation issues you will eventually have when using `varchar`, but it will be slower in query performance than `varchar`. [Great DBA question](http://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/5346/why-is-there-still-a-varchar-data-type) with further info.

Comment: How did this question get so many upvotes? So it says which data type to use, fine... but it doesn't even try to explain *why* that would be the right choice.

Comment: You can always use varchar and escape any unicode chars. This is a good approach if you will only have occasional unicode chars in your text as it saves space over using a nvarchar

Comment: I down voted great to voice an option I want to know why there is none provided

Comment: It doesn't really matter if you use varchar(max) or nvarchar(max).  You can store unicode to either, you'll just need to convert it as necessary on the receiving side.  I.e. convert input to bytes, convert bytes to varchar(max), write to varchar(max), when retrieving, convert to bytes, convert to unicode.  Or vice versa if you have nvarchar(max).  You can convert the input to ascii, then to bytes, then write to nvarchar(max).  Yeah it's ugly, but if you get in a pinch you can store w/e you want  in unicode or non unicode field.

Answer (score 4):

Recommended data type is **NVARCHAR**.
Please refer
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/json/json-data-sql-server?view=sql-server-ver15#store-and-index-json-data-in-sql-server][1]

Comment: The page you link to doesn't make any such recommendation. It just says "JSON text is stored in VARCHAR or NVARCHAR columns and is indexed as plain text. " - it uses `NVARCHAR` in all the examples which is understandable as it has no idea what characters people will be using this code with

Answer (score 3):

I would recommend to use `nvarchar(max)` if you plan to use JSON features on SQL 2016 or Azure SQL.

If you don't plan to use those features, you could use `varbinary(max)` combined with `COMPRESS` (and `DECOMPRESS`) functions. More information: https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/sqlserverstorageengine/2015/11/23/storing-json-in-sql-server/

> COMPRESS and DECOMPRESS functions use standard GZip compression. If your client can handle GZip compression (e.g browser that understands gzip content), you can directly return compressed content. Note that this is performance/storage trade-off. If you frequently query compressed data you mig have slower performance because text must be decompressed each time.

Comment: which are ***JSON features on SQL 2016*** ?